# Multiple IF statements in ajaxSuccess giving the same result

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Very simply put, in the ajaxSuccess part, of my GET method, for retrieving data, I have 12 `if`s like so:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/Appointments/', 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if ((result.AppTime == "9:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "9:30") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "10:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "10:30") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "11:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }

                else {
                    alert("error1");
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            },
        });
    });
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
  private AjanvarusEntities2 db = new AjanvarusEntities2();
    [HttpGet]
    public List<AppointmentsDT> ReturnApps()
    {
        List<AppointmentsDT> list = new List<AppointmentsDT>();

        foreach (Appointment a in db.Appointments)
        {
            AppointmentsDT a1 = new AppointmentsDT();
            a1.AppWithYritys = a.AppWithYritys;
            a1.AppTime = a.AppTime;

            list.Add(a1);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

depending on the data retrieved from the database, it should color the appropriate `div`, as You can see, but it is coloring all of the `div`s and I know that the only thing that exists in the database and can be retrieved is the first if, only the first if is true. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**
I have added the controller and the whole ajax to provide more insight into the code.

Comment: Yes for JavaScript. Use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`

Comment: @Traktor53 when i add `==` it gives me the `else` statement, and doesn't color any `div` for some reason, only `=` works...maybe it is a problem with the controller? or the ajax method itself?

Comment: An assignment expression of form `(variableName = "non-null-string")` automatically converts to `true` when tested as a boolean value. The problem is with the code posted, possibly followed by a problem with the property values of  the `result` object.

Comment: @Traktor53 i will edit the question and add the whole ajax and the controller, that way You can get the whole picture, and maybe find the mistake i couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using incorrect operator in your `IF` statement. you should use `==` instead of `=`

```
 success: function (result) {
                if ((result.AppTime == "9:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "9:30") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "10:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "10:30") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
                if ((result.AppTime == "11:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                }
```

also, I think your conditions can be simplified further:

```
success: function (result) {
    if ((result.AppTime == "9:00") && (result.AppWithYritys == "Laakkonen")) {
      document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
    }

    if ((result.AppTime == "9:30" || result.AppTime == "10:00" || result.AppTime = "10:30" || result.AppTime = "11:00") && (result.AppWithYritys = "Laakkonen")) {
      document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
    }
```

better yet, if you have only more than 2 possible results in `result.AppWithYritys`, you can write nested switches:

```
switch (result.AppWithYritys) {
    case: "Laakkonen": {
        switch(result.Apptime) {
            case "9:00":
                document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
                break;
            case "9:30":
                document.getElementById("A930").style.background = "red";
                break;
               ........

        }
    }
    case "Other_case2": {
         //switch-case statement again here for result.AppTime?
    }
......
//other cases for result.AppWithYritys
}
```

Comment: the nested switch is a good idea, since i have a lot of those companies like "Laakkonen" and because when I use `==` operator i get the else statment which is in my case for telling me somethings wrong, because the only item in the table is Laakkonen 9:00 and that is it, and I don't know why it doesn't return me anything.

Comment: tried the switch, still isn't working :/ maybe it could be a problem with the controller, but then why would it work with `=` operator...

Comment: try `console.log(result.AppWithYritys)` and `console.log(result.Apptime)`, if they are the same always, there might be something wrong with your controller.

Comment: can you update your question and add the `switch-case` you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

**As discussed in comment**

A comparison operator for equality should be used to test if a field in the reply has a particular value. If some cases automatic type conversions performed in JavaScript can produce unexpected results, so there is a choice between the type-converting equality operator '==' and the strict equality operator `===`.

An assignment expression that sets an object property or named variable to a non empty string always evaluate to `true` when used as a boolean value in a conditional statement.

**A new problem**

Noticed after the last question update, the HTML element with id `A930` is being used to highlight the 10:00, 10:30, 11:00 appointments as well. This is almost certainly not the intended result.

A *suggestion* for code that produces specific error and warning messages that may be of assistance is as follows. Please note it has not been tested.

```
var timeId = {
        "9:00": "A900",
        "9:30": "A930",
        "10:00": "A1000",
        "10:30": "A1030",
        "11:00": "A1100"   //, and so
    };


var id = timeId[ reply.AppTime]; // validate appointment time

if( !id) {
    console.log("Unknown appointment time: " + reply.AppTime);
}
else if( reply.AppWithYritys != "Laakkonen") {
    console.log("AppWithYritys location is: " + result.AppWithYritys);
}
else {
    document.getElementById( id).style.background = "red";
}
```